# Cocoa dispatch keyboard events

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I need to make an app similar to a virtual keyboard, but much more simplified, it will have the direcional keys and 4 more buttons ( to be configured ). It's basicly a virtual gamepad like a playstation or xbox.
The aim is to use this on an interactive display to play a series of simple games that might give them a prize.

My question is, can i press the button "X" on my gamepad and than send to my operative system that the user pressed a certain letter? this is regardless of the application the user has open, i want this to work in the background and can send these events to any game the user is playing.

btw, this will be working on mac osx 10.8.x